# Invalid template file error Magento 2.4.4?

Tags: magento2.4.4

I installed https://github.com/DivanteLtd/magento2-vsbridge-pagebuilder/tree/develop this module to use convert cms page builder content HTML to JSON format. But only the banner, image, and video elements are working. Widget-related components are not working like products, the block is not working

I am getting below error

> Error filtering template: Invalid template file:
> 'Divante_VsbridgePageBuilder::product/widget/content/grid.phtml' in
> module: 'Divante_VsbridgePageBuilder' block's name:
> 'product\productslist_0'

I checked all folder path all is correct even though I am getting an error

Please give me a solution.